# How to change ProgressView accentColor in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This doesn't apply

```
ProgressView("\(spinnerLabel)")
    .accentColor(.white)
```

This changes the label

```
.foregroundColor(.white)
```

[image]

Comment: `.accentColor(.white)` seems to be working again in 2021/22. As described in [this tutorial](https://serialcoder.dev/text-tutorials/swiftui/progressview-in-swiftui/)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try the following:

For iOS15+

```
.tint(.white)
```

For iOS13+

```
.progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: Color.white))
```

Comment: is there a way to make the tint color as gradient for the PrgoressView

Answer (score 8):

The selected answer contains a deprecated method, `init(tint:)`.

This is the new way to change the tint color:

```
ProgressView()
    .tint(.white)
```

Answer (score 3):

## SwiftUI 3

`.tint(Color)` changes the current progress color while `.background()` changes the background of the progress view.

```
ProgressView(value: summary.ratio)
    .tint(.white)
    .background(.black)
```

[image]